AttributeError: module 'pydot' has no attribute 'InvocationException'
Problem:

I want to use plot_model from keras.utils to draw a beautiful AI model layers map;
The tool plot_model requires "pydot" and "graphviz";
I installed "pydot" using Anaconda Prompt (pip install pydot), and "graphviz" using the installer EXE;
Instead of a beautiful graph, I'm getting AttributeError: module 'pydot' has no attribute 'InvocationException'.

Question: how to make the error go away and the code run correctly?
Edit:
The error AttributeError: module 'pydot' has no attribute 'InvocationException' is caused by a  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path. error, that is caused by a FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado error.

to make sure Graphviz is correctly installed, on a command line, what happens when you enter: dot -V

On Anaconda Prompt? dot is not recognized.

not an Anaconda prompt, a "cmd" prompt for Windows or a shell-level prompt for Mac or Linux

Also not recognized.

probably not installed.  Please describe exactly what an "graphviz" using the installer EXE entailed

I went to https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/#windows, downloaded the "windows_10_cmake_Release_graphviz-install-12.0.0-win64.exe" file on the "graphviz-12.0.0 (64-bit) EXE installer" link, and run the exe file.

sounds right, you should be able to bring up a "cmd" window, type "dot -V" and see a "version" result - just to double-check

I redid the installation, with the settings "Do not add Graphviz to the system PATH" and "E:\Programas\Graphviz", and was not able to get dot on cmd nor use it on Spyder IDE.

You want to add to system PATH (assuming you own the computer)

Fine, I changed the default setting to "Add Graphviz to the system PATH for current user", and now dot -V works, returning "dot - graphviz version 12.0.0 (20240704.0754)". Still get the same errors on Spyder when running plot_model(model, show_shapes = True, to_file='sent_analysis_model.png').

It is a pydot version incompatibility, as seen on GitHub.
Do pip install pydot==2.0.0 and it will work, as said by syedalimohsinbukhari.

It was a pydot version incompatibility. Doing pip install pydot==2.0.0 solved the problem. Refer to: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/19040#issuecomment-2159732159
